# If the value exists show in wordpress admin (Form's have been created on the fly so number increments)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm creating my first options page and i'm trying to upload images for a slider, I don't know how many images are going to be in the slider so I will need to add more with a + button, It will automatically show one text input an upload button and a + button to start off with, should I require more i'll click the + button which will then add another text input, upload button a + button and a - button.

I've got this working to a point, it still needs a little help but it's getting there  http://jsfiddle.net/vs8p5/5/

So far if I upload an image and click the + button, it will give me the option to upload another, this is working great and the images upload to wordpress.

Now for the issue.

I'm using this part of code to retrieve the data from wordpress

```
if( isset( $hero_options['upload_image_link_1'] ) && $hero_options[ 'upload_image_link_1' ] ) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('yes it has');</script>";
}
```

This tells me that if there is a value then echo the alert

Now, working form that code above I've

```
function kandibox_hero_upload_image_link_callback($args) {
    $hero_options = get_option( 'hero_options' ); ?>
    <div id="upload_image_sets">   <?php
    $hero_options = get_option ( 'hero_options' ); 
if( isset( $hero_options['upload_image_link_1'] ) && $hero_options[ 'upload_image_link_1' ] ) { ?>
  <div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
        <input id="upload_image_link_1" type="text" size="36" name="hero_options[upload_image_link_1]" value="<?php echo $hero_options['upload_image_link_1']; ?>" /> 
        <input id="show_upload_image_link_button_1" class="button upload_images" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
        <div class="actions">
          <button class="clone">Clone</button> 
          <button class="remove">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div> <?php
}
    else { ?>
      <div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
        <input id="upload_image_link_1" type="text" size="36" name="hero_options[upload_image_link_1]" value="<?php echo $hero_options['upload_image_link_1']; ?>" /> 
        <input id="show_upload_image_link_button_1" class="button upload_images" type="button" value="Upload Image" />

        <div class="actions">
          <button class="clone">Clone</button> 
          <button class="remove">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div> <?php
}
```

What i'm trying to do here is echo a form with a value, if nothing exists, echo a blank form, this seems to work although I don't think it's correct.

The main issue is that it will only echo the first form, when you click the + buttons, the form's id, name, and value script increments.

So now the question.

How can I get the form to look for all the $hero_options['upload_image_link_...'] and echo out a form for each if it exists? then echo out 1 blank form if nothing exists?

I'm pretty sure i've covered everything you might need but if i've missed something, let me know and i'll add it.

I've followed about 20 tutorials old and new and come up with this.

To add the information to the wordpress database, i'm using the following code.

```
function register_hero_options() {

add_settings_section(
    'hero_settings_section',            // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options
    __( 'hero Options', 'kandibox' ),   // Title to be displayed on the administration page
    'kandibox_hero_options_callback',   // Callback used to render the description of the section
    'hero_options'                      // Page on which to add this section of options
);

add_settings_field( 
    'show_hero_options',                // ID used to identify the field throughout the theme
    __( 'hero', 'kandibox' ),           // The label to the left of the option interface element
    'kandibox_toggle_hero_callback',    // The name of the function responsible for rendering the option interface
    'hero_options',                     // The page on which this option will be displayed
    'hero_settings_section'             // The name of the section to which this field belongs
);

$hero_options = get_option ( 'hero_options' ); 
if( isset( $hero_options['show_hero_options'] ) && $hero_options[ 'show_hero_options' ] ) {

    add_settings_field( 
        'hero_size',                        
        __( 'Size', 'kandibox' ),                           
        'kandibox_hero_size_callback',  
        'hero_options', 
        'hero_settings_section'         
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'hero_background',                      
        __( 'Background', 'kandibox' ),                         
        'kandibox_hero_background_callback',    
        'hero_options', 
        'hero_settings_section'         
    ); 

        add_settings_field( 
            'upload_image_links',                       
            __( 'Upload Image', 'kandibox' ),                           
            'kandibox_hero_upload_image_link_callback', 
            'hero_options', 
            'hero_settings_section'         
        );

}

register_setting(
    'hero_options',
    'hero_options'
);

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_hero_options' );
```

Comment: how are you updating the link in the option table. can you show how its being store so that we can find a method to fetch the uploaded url in a loop

Comment: @anstrangel0ver I'm using the wordpress add_settings_field( and register_setting(), I've updated the posts to show you the full code.

Comment: can your var_dumb[$hero_options]; and check what array its storing

Comment: @anstrangel0ver Sorry took so long, i'm learning as I go along, never used var_dump before. Here are the results array(6) { ["show_hero_options"]=> string(1) "1" ["hero_height"]=> string(2) "65" ["hero_width"]=> string(2) "42" ["hero_background"]=> string(0) "" ["upload_image_link_1"]=> string(6) "daniel" ["upload_image_link_2"]=> string(4) "john" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$hero_options = get_option( 'hero_options' ); 
$count=count($hero_options);
$totalimg=$count-4; ?>
<div id="upload_image_sets"> <?php
if( isset( $hero_options['upload_image_link_1'] ) && $hero_options[ 'upload_image_link_1' ] ) { 
for($i=1;$i<=$totalimg;$i++){ ?>
<div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
<input type="text" size="36" name="hero_options[upload_image_link_<?=$i ?>]" value="<?php echo $hero_options['upload_image_link_'.$i]; ?>" />
  <input id="show_upload_image_link_button_1" class="button upload_images" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
  <div class="actions">
    <button class="clone">Clone</button> 
    <button class="remove">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div> <?php
}}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i juss wrote a rough code for you might this will help you. this is according to the array you have go. there might be some better ways of doing it.

```
$hero_options = get_option( 'hero_options' ); 
$count=count($hero_options);
$totalimg=$count-4; ?>
<div id="upload_image_sets"> <?php
if( isset( $hero_options['upload_image_link_1'] ) && $hero_options[ 'upload_image_link_1' ] ) { 
for($i=1;$i<=$totalimg;$i++){ ?>
    <div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
  <input type="text" size="36" name="hero_options[upload_image_link_<?=$i ?>]" value="<?php echo $hero_options['upload_image_link_'.$i]; ?>" />
      <input id="show_upload_image_link_button_1" class="button upload_images" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
      <div class="actions">
        <button class="clone">Clone</button> 
        <button class="remove">Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div> <?php
}}
?>
</div> <?php
```

Updated the code so now it's correct.

Comment: Hi there's a syntax code on this line for($i=1,$i<$totalimg,$i++){ ?> but this part means nothing to me, the rest of it all makes sense

Comment: Sorry, What does that mean?

Comment: i have changed  for($i=1,$i<$totalimg,$i++) as for($i=1;$i<=$totalimg;$i++){ in my answer .. see above

Comment: Damn, I just figured that out and was just about to post

Comment: just testing it now and i'll let you know. Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48362/discussion-between-user1221565-and-anstrangel0ver)